# CKEditor disable all toolbar buttons on blur when using Shared Space plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, toolbar

I am using CKEditor 4.7 in combination with the Shared Space plugin. In my page I have multiple CKEditor text blocks and some plain text inputs. I used the Shared Space plugin so the toolbar will be on top of the page all the time. Unfortunately the Shared Space plugin does not disable the toolbar when the focus is not on a CKEditor field (which is petty bad UI experience).

So to solve this I added a custom plugin that disables all buttons when the editor blurs and enables it again when it gets focus. All working beautifully except there are a couple of stubborn buttons that won't disable, even though the new selection does not provide them any context they can use.

These are the ones: **colorbutton, format and spellchecker.**

[image]

I just don't understand why these little brats won't comply??

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('common', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.on('blur', function() {
            Object.keys(editor.commands).forEach(function (key){
                editor.commands[key].disable();
            });
        });

        editor.on('focus', function() {
            Object.keys(editor.commands).forEach(function (key){
                editor.commands[key].enable();
            });
        });
    }
} );
```